# Rerendering meteor.js on window resize?

Tags: user-interface, resize, meteor

Anybody figure out syntax to re-render a template on window resize, using Meteor.js?  I tried doing a Meteor.flush(), but that doesn't seem to be the right approach....  :(

```
window.onresize = function(){
    Meteor.flush();
};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change some session value when resizing the window, and then just have the template listen for that change:

```
<template name="body">
  {{touch}}
</template>

Template.body.touch = function() {
  return Session.get("touch");
}

Meteor.startup(function() {
  $(window).resize(function(evt) {
    Session.set("touch", new Date());
  });
});
```

Comment: *That* is totally clever.  I'm off to give it a try!  :)

Comment: date only updates once per second. here's an approach which is more responsive if needed `Session.set("touch", $(window).width() + $(window).height());`

Answer (score 0):

Meteor docs provides a good example for this scenario, by the way of adding window dimensions as a Client-side global Reactive data source, which could be called on 
Template->autorun()
https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#stores